# running selenium as a RC in IE, as a scheduled task

Tags: selenium, automation, scheduled-tasks, selenium-rc

I'm trying to automate a task using Selenium-RC where the user doesn't have to be logged in. Here's the ideal scenario:

Running as a scheduled task and the user is not logged in. 
Selenium will start at a scheduled task, open IE and go about the script.

I'm not sure this is possible, but I need to simulate user interactions with IE without the user being logged in. what would be the best way to do this?

IDEA:

would I able to put Selenium  on a virtual machine, have the virtual machine run as a scheduled task on a physical machine; so when the user is logged out the virtual machine can still be started, and selenium will run on the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ant build, you could create a batch file to invoke the build. Now you could schedule the execution of batch.

I suppose you could same while using TestNG framework with java. So you create a batch file for executing test using testng.xml and then have it scheduled.

Comment: My problem is that I need Selenium or RFT to run while the computer is locked. 
I'm not sure if a virtual machine. have a batch process start up VMware to turn on the virtual machine, and have selenium run on the VM.

Comment: Selenium execution using a batch file should not be an issue when your computer is locked.

Comment: I need to automate a task in IE (for example sending an email) using selenium. Will I able to do this while the computer is Locked/notLoggedIn?